# Why git add <<<<<<<<HEAD on top of my files

Tags: git

I did

```
git add -A .
```

then

```
git commit -m "message"
```

and then

```
git push origin master
```

then it gaves some error and said "git pull.. etc"

i did

```
git pull origin master
```

it gaves error about "merge conflict"

and then i did

```
git push origin master
```

but now i check my files i see in some of my files there are some codes

[image: codes]

How can i correct my files. Should i remove that codes manually ? Or is there any automatic method ?

Thanks for all

Comment: (It looks like the merge conflicts weren't addressed :>)

Comment: And what should i do now ? Couldnt remove that codes ?

Comment: You fix the merge conflicts :-) Then you add those files to the index again and then you commit

Answer (score 2):

These are called the conflict markers. These are the parts which GIT couldnt merge automatically.

You can check [Resolve a Merge](http://schacon.github.io/git/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge) and then commit your changes

Answer (score 0):

After `git pull`, resolve conflict

then again commit changes and do `git pull/push`

Comment: How can i resolve conflict ?

Comment: @MuhammetArslan:- Did you checked the link which I have added in my answer. That tells you the way how to resolve the conflict!

Comment: from your snapshot, put only part either from head or with your changes, if both are same, put any one, and also remove line start with >>>>, and you are done.

Comment: @user3414693 yeah i check and now reading it. but maybe Vinit know any other thing , right ? Thanks for all. I will try and write